# az vmss delete ..., error: argument --force-deletion: expected one argument

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cloud-shell

I read document at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/delete?tabs=portal2%2Ccli3%2Cportal4%2Ccli5#force-delete-for-scale-sets

My command

```
az vmss delete --resource-group myResourceGroup_vy --name WindowsVM --force-deletion
```

Error

```
argument --force-deletion: expected one argument

Examples from AI knowledge base:
az vmss delete --name myscaleset --resource-group myresourcegroup
Deletes a VM scale set. (autogenerated)

az vmss delete --name myscaleset
Deletes a VM scale set. (autogenerated)

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/cli/azure/vmss#az_vmss_delete
Read more about the command in reference docs
```

Full content of Azure cloud shell https://gist.github.com/donhuvy/95c3f431d3f7a7824b3dd3f29ffd30eb

[image]

How to fix it? I just follow step-by-step document, but maybe reference document was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Created one Virtual machine scale set in my resource group like below:

[image]

When I ran same command to delete it, I got  **same error**  as you like below:

```
az vmss delete --resource-group myResourceGroup_vy --name WindowsVM --force-deletion
```

[image]

To delete the Virtual machine scale set, make use of below command:

```
az vmss delete --resource-group <RGName> --name <VmssName>--force-deletion true
```

According to the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/delete?tabs=portal2,cli3,portal4,cli5#force-delete-for-scale-sets) when I add `true` in the command vmss deleted successfully like below.

***Output***:

[image]